# Post Album to Facebook Business Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing a program to add a photo album to a company web-site and simultaneously post it to the company's facebook page. So far, the web-site album post works well, but I'm having issues posting it to facebook. I am using the new SDK 4, have set up an app in facebook under the admin's facebook page, and successfully created a session that can get all of the company album information, but when I try to POST a new album to the business page, I get this error:

'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#100) Invalid ID for album owner'

I have been having problems finding anything helpful on the facebook developer web-site, can anyone here point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once("php/facebook/autoload.php");

session_start();

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// start session

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'APP_ID','SECRET' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('test.php' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/BUSINESS PAGE ID/albums' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'POST',
      '/BUSINESS PAGE ID/albums',
      array (
        'name' => 'Test Album',
        'message' => 'This is for testing purposes only',
      )
  );
  $newAlbumID = $request->execute();

  // print data
  echo 'New Album ID: '.$newAlbumID.'<br />';
  //echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!